# ui_mainwindow.h file not found

Tags: c++, qt

[Errors recieved when trying to run the program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R1BFy.png)

I am fairly new to QT and recently ive gotten stuck on the error "ui_mainwindow.h file not found". I have tried most fixes I could find online and I have reinstalled different versions of QT multiple times to try and fix it. Ill attach my code below.

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QApplication>

QT_BEGIN_NAMESPACE
namespace Ui{class MainWindow;}
QT_END_NAMESPACE

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();


};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "CommandWords.h"
#include "Room.h"
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QPixmap>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    setFixedSize(1000,1000);

}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

.pro file:

```
QT += core gui

TEMPLATE = app
CONFIG += console c++11
CONFIG -= app_bundle

SOURCES += \
    Character.cpp \
    Command.cpp \
    CommandWords.cpp \
    Parser.cpp \
    Room.cpp \
    ZorkUL.cpp \
    item.cpp \
    mainwindow.cpp

HEADERS += \
    Character.h \
    Command.h \
    CommandWords.h \
    Parser.h \
    Room.h \
    ZorkUL.h \
    item.h \
    mainwindow.h

FORMS += mainwindow.ui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets
```

Comment: Look at the last error in QtCreator. `No rule to make target mainwindow.ui`. There is some error in the preprocessing of your UI-file

Comment: when i look in the directory the ui file isnt generating.